# Where can I find a crop calendar for Arizona

Tags: urban-gardening, square-foot-gardening

I'm starting a community garden but so far all the crop calendars I've been able to find don't seem to have Arizona weather in mind. Anyone know where I can find a local crop calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try some of these calendars for Arizona:

https://www.ufseeds.com/Arizona-Vegetable-Planting-Calendar.html

https://www.almanac.com/gardening/planting-calendar/AZ/Phoenix